# Does vertical align CSS property ever work?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

W3School says :

> When we use `vertical-align:middle;` The element is placed in the
>   middle of the parent element

So I tried to do that, But didn't get desired outcome

**CODE :**

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
p {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  text
  <p>
    yo bro
  </p>
</div>
```

Why m I not getting the desired outcome ?

Comment: It only affects alignment for inline items like text.  You want flex.

Comment: I have used the property in both the places and it did'nt work in even one of them

Comment: And inline items are vertical aligned to line-height. So, add `line-height: 200px` to your div and you'll see.

Comment: Don't trust w3schools. `vertical-align` does not behave like that.

Comment: @Oriol Could you please tell a better  and reliable source

Comment: @Rasik [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is usually very good. Or [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align).

Comment: @Rasik - There is one very good article on the web that properly explains the vertical-align property. I highly recommend you read http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/

Comment: Exactly what I Googled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

because `vertical-align` only applies to inline level and table-cell elements. Both `div` and `p` are block level elements.

> **Applies to**    inline-level and table-cell elements. It also applies to
>   `::first-letter` and `::first-line`.

[MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

With that in mind and using your example make your `div` a `table` and your `p` a `table-cell`

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: table
}
p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    yo bro
  </p>
</div>
```

**NOTE**: Don't trust W3Schools as source, instead use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or [W3C Specs](https://www.w3.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Add to `div` in css `display: table-cell` ;

```
div {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 200px; 
   width: 500px; 
   background: red; 
   text-align:center;
   vertical-align: middle; 
}
p {}
```

Comment: Is "display:table-cell;" valid CSS?

Comment: @Sparky256 it is but should have a parent displaying as a table, which in this case doesn't have. Look at my answer and you will see that in action

Comment: @dippas. I see that now. Almost had a brain f*art. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

try using, `line-height` in styling, as shown below, or fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/f9ag6t5m/)

```css
 div{
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
p{
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
  line-height: 100px;

}
```

```html
<div>
  text
  <p>
    yo bro
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops that's a good question, I did it for only single line, Let me sort it out.

Comment: In that case you need to use the css code as https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/f9ag6t5m/2/

Comment: @ Riot exactly as my answer I posted

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your posted code.

Firstly, you haven't really explained what your desired outcome is so it's hard to help you with your specific problem.

Assuming you want to align the paragraph text with the other text in the div, you'll have to add `display:inline-block;` to your paragraph. Then, the trick with vertical aligning is to use `line-height`as well as `height`. Set them both the same and voilá, things line up nicely.

```
div{
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
   line-height:200px;
  background: red;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
p{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

[codepen here](http://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/XdYrrW)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use `FlexBox` you could do it this way.

```
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

This makes things centred both ways.  If you want it just to be the height then delete `justify-content`.  Note that you need to do `flex-direction: column` in this example to make the content go down the page and not sit side-to-side.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  yo
  <p>bro</p>
</div>
```